# Calling Webservice in iPhone application?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ios4, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using soap webservice.

In that i am calling one webmethod. Here if i call  from one part of my code is working fine and calling service successfully and retriving data successfully.

But if i calling same method from another part of code of same class is not responding and not getting any data from service. Why is going like that can any one help me please.

Thanks in advance

In detail.m

```
-(void) downloadAndParse:(NSMutableURLRequest *)sentReq  {

    conn =  [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:sentReq delegate:self];

    if (conn) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
}

-(void)fullBarcodeSearch:(NSString *)code {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    URLRequest *r  = [[URLRequest alloc] init];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [r fullBarcodeSearch:code];
    [r release];
    [self downloadAndParse:req];

}
```

In URLRequest.m

```
-(NSMutableURLRequest *) addHeaderToSoapXML:(NSString *) soapMsg {



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMsg length]];
    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    return req;
}
```

if service not called then i am getting error like this

***oid _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x6958130: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.***

Please any one help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need an NSURLConnection to execute the NSURLRequest. Lookup the Apple Docs on the class.
Something like:

```
[urlConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse: &urlResponse error:&error]
```

Comment: what shoud have to write in the place of response  &urlResponse

Comment: oid _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x6958130: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.
 i am getting error like this Please help me thanks in advance